# Copy files twice using xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, xp-cmdshell

When I run this command

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'copy C:\---\cmdshell1\a23.txt C:\---\cmdshell2';
```

It copies a23.txt file from cmdshell1 to cmdshell2 folder.

When I run the same command second time it does not copy the same a23.txt file to folder cmdshell2 for second time.
So after running xp_cmdshell command multiple times I only get one file in cmdshell2 which was generated the first time. 
My question is, how to write this command in order to copy the a23.txt file from cmdshell1 folder into cmdshell2 the amount of times I ran the query(if I have run the above query 3 times, I want to have 3 copies of a23.txt file in cmdshell2).

Comment: Do you get the results you want if you run that command outside of `xp_cmdshell`?

Comment: Do you mean in basic Command Prompt @sp_BlitzErik? While running on Command prompt is asks whether to overwrite or not..

Comment: @EolaGiba - Is it ok to put a timestamp on each file in the target folder to make the files unique?

Comment: Yes, @ScottHodgin

Comment: That is the normal behavior of xp_cmdshell and just command shell.  It will not create a new file if a file exists.    You have to make them unique. Can you use powershell for this?  Or call powershell.exe from your prompt?

Comment: I don't know whether is it possible or not @AliRazeghi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of building a dynamic `xp_cmdshell` command that includes a timestamp on the file

```
declare @Cmd varchar(100)
set @Cmd = 'copy C:\test\a23.txt C:\test\a23-' + replace(replace(convert(varchar(19),sysdatetime()),' ','-'),':','-') + '.txt'
print @cmd
exec xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

Comment: I prefer Scotts answer to mine but i'll leave my answer up in case it helps someone else in the future.  Scotts answer doesn't require you to drop into powershell from xp_cmdshell while my solution does.

Answer (score 0):

That is the normal behavior of xp_cmdshell and just command shell.  It will not create a new file if a file exists.    You have to make them unique. This worked for me.

First create this script and put it in a folder, I use a scripts folder. I named it cptimestamps.ps1.

```
$src = "C:\cmdshell1\1.txt"; 
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd-ms; 
$dst = "C:\cmdshell2\1-$($date).txt"; 
Copy-Item $src $dst
```

Then execute powershell.exe from cmd by using:

```
powershell.exe -command c:\scripts\cptimestamp.ps1
```

This worked fine for me.  Make sure your powershell [execution policy](https://www.adamtheautomator.com/set-executionpolicy/) is set.  In many environments people just do a `set-exeuctionpolicy -executionpolicy Unrestricted`